# Are new AWS AMD instances using SMT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amd

I recall when AMD EYPC was first released on AWS EC, it was not using SMT: one vCPU was one full physical core.

Is this still the case for new AMD instances?

Answer (score 0):

Each Hyper-Thread for a system will appear to the kernel as a logical CPU core. There may be multiple cores per physical socket, as demonstrated by the lscpu utility:

```
# lscpu | grep -e Socket -e Core -e Thread
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
```

Article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/rhel-smt